# What is the correct url helper for my cart in magento top links

Tags: xml, magento

I am trying to rearrange the order of the top links using a local.xml file and so far everything is going well, however for the cart I keep getting an non existent url.

At first I just added the block back into the top links in the following manner

```
<reference name="top.links.custom">
  <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>130</position></action>

  <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Home</label><url helper="core/url/getHomeUrl"/><title>Home</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>50</position></action>
  <block type="checkout/links" name="check_cart_link_custom">
    <action method="addCartLink"></action>
</block>
```

which worked by adding in my cart. So then I wanted to position it as the last link so I figured I could use the following snippet

```
<reference name="top.links.custom">
      <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>130</position></action>
      <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Home</label><url helper="core/url/getHomeUrl"/><title>Home</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>50</position></action>
      <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="checkout"><label>Cart</label><url helper="checkout/cart/"/><title>Cart</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>150</position></action>
</reference>
```

neither this or using "addCartLink" works.So what is the correct way to do use addLink for my cart in the toplinks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="checkout">
    <label>Cart</label>
    <url helper="checkout/url/getCartUrl"/>
    <title>Cart</title>
    <prepare/>
    <urlParams/>
    <position>150</position>
</action>
```

Comment: this makes the link work, but unlike when you use `<block type="checkout/links" name="check_cart_link_custom">
    <action method="addCartLink"></action>
</block>` to add a product to the cart there is not an indication that something is in cart. So instead of showing (Cart 1 item) it is just (Cart). Is it not possible to do it this way?

Comment: To get the (Cart) effect, all you need is to edit the mini cart view and remove the item counter variable.

Comment: how can I add icon instead of `label` cart

Comment: Replace: `<label>Cart</label>` with `<label><![CDATA[<img src="IMAGE_FULL_PATH">]]></label>`. FYI I have never tested the code but it should work. Let me know how it goes. Thx